# Trouble with name iterations for Html.DropDownList

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

I have a table where each row contains fields for a form.

I iterate in the view using this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) { }
```

Within the foreach, I create a new table row with various fields contained inside.  e.g.:

```
<tr><td> @Html.DropDownList("granny", "") </td></tr>
```

"granny" is being passed via the controller, and looks a bit like this:

```
ViewData["granny"] = new SelectList(db.getGrannies(), "grannyid", "grannyname");
```

Everything's working pretty well.  The view is getting its grannies, and everything looks good.  I noticed however that the name property of the field { e.g....

```
<select id="granny" name="granny">
```

} is the exact same for EVERY row created.  This is a problem.  I want to toss this data back to the controller in the form of a FormCollection and do fun stuff with all these grannies.  I can't do that if they're not all getting passed.

That is, I'd like the selects to read, instead, like this:

```
<select id="granny1" name="granny1">
<select id="granny2" name="granny2">
```

I researched the problem a bit, and tried using

```
new { @Name="xyz" + n }
```

But Visual Studio didn't like that much.

---

The short and sweet of it all is this:

**How do I give ViewData-generated Html.DropDownLists their own unique ids/names?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I give ViewData-generated Html.DropDownLists their own unique ids/names?

You cannot change the `name` of the generated input field and this is by design. Only the id could be changed. This being said you shouldn't need to do that. You could do the following:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) 
{ 
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownList(
                "selectedGranny", 
                (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["granny"]
            )
        </td>
    </tr>    
}
```

Comment: That worked.  Also, converting it to a strictly typed view went a long way, as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are either trying to databind a collection, or you just need to manually name your selects (as they are really different controls on the web form).

You can use the following overload to pass html parameters to the drop down :

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "CategoryID", 
    (SelectList)ViewBag.CategoryId, 
    "--Select One--", 
    new{  //anonymous type
          name = "granny1",
          @class = "myCssClass", 
          onchange = "someFunction();"
       })
```

Comment: I tried giving her a name, and she didn't do anything with it whatsoever.  That is, it resulted in no changes to the rendered name.

Converting her to a strictly typed view, for whatever reason, seemed to work.  Thanks for your help and time.